# jQuery still not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make it so when the user moves the mouse arrow over each of the desc1, desc2 and desc3 div, the corresponding map appears but none of the maps are hidden when the page and jQuery script runs.

```
<head>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"     type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-1.10.1.js'></script>
</head>

<div id="desc1" class="descriptions">Head Office Map</div>
<div id="desc2" class="descriptions">Office Map 2</div>
<div id="desc3" class="descriptions">Office Map 3</div>
<div id="themaps1" class="mymaps"> Head Office Map <img src="map1.jpg"/> </div>
<div id="themaps2" class="mymaps"> Office Map2 <img src="map2.jpg"/></div>
<div id="themaps3" class="mymaps"> Office Map3 <img src="map3.jpg"/> </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$('.mymaps').hide( );

$('#desc1').on('mouseover', function() {    
        $('#themaps1').fadeIn();
    });.on('mouseout', function() {
         $('#themaps1').fadeOut();
    });


        $('#desc2').on('mouseover', function() {    
        $('#themaps2').fadeIn();
    });.on('mouseout', function() {
        $('#themaps2').fadeOut();
    });

            $('#desc3').on('mouseover', function() {    
        $('#themaps3').fadeIn();
    });.on('mouseout', function() {
        $('#themaps3').fadeOut();
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Why are you loading jQuery twice?

Comment: I'd put it in `$(function() { $('.mymaps').hide( ); });` so it runs after document ready.

Comment: Get rid of the semicolon between your ons `;.on`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are errors in your jQuery code. Remove the three semicolons after `)` and before `.on`

```
});.on
```

Also refer to Pinals answer, only include jquery once.

Then for good practise, add the `hide()` function into a document ready function (even if it should run anyway):

```
$(function()
{
  $('.mymaps').hide();
});
```

Working jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/C49AW/

Answer (score 1):

Remove one of jQuery files:

> ```
> <script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
> <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-1.10.1.js'></script>
> ```

Use jQuery Ready Event and remove `;` Syntax Errors:

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
> $(function () {
>     $('.mymaps').hide( );
>
>     $('#desc1').on('mouseover', function() {    
>         $('#themaps1').fadeIn();
>     }).on('mouseout', function() {
>          $('#themaps1').fadeOut();
>     });
>
>
>     $('#desc2').on('mouseover', function() {    
>         $('#themaps2').fadeIn();
>     }).on('mouseout', function() {
>         $('#themaps2').fadeOut();
>     });
>
>     $('#desc3').on('mouseover', function() {    
>         $('#themaps3').fadeIn();
>     }).on('mouseout', function() {
>         $('#themaps3').fadeOut();
>     });
> });
> </script>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct in that you have an extra semicolon before every call of .on(...) and two jQuery includes. I wanted to point out though, that there is a much easier way to go about this. By simply adding a custom data-attribute to each of your descriptions, you can build one function that does everything. Like this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kpjava/8c8vW/2/):

```
<head>
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<div id="desc1" class="descriptions" data-map="#themaps1">Head Office Map</div>
<div id="desc2" class="descriptions" data-map="#themaps2">Office Map 2</div>
<div id="desc3" class="descriptions" data-map="#themaps3">Office Map 3</div>
<div id="themaps1" class="mymaps"> Head Office Map <img src="map1.jpg"/> </div>
<div id="themaps2" class="mymaps"> Office Map2 <img src="map2.jpg"/></div>
<div id="themaps3" class="mymaps"> Office Map3 <img src="map3.jpg"/> </div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
  $('.mymaps').hide( );

  $('[data-map]').each(function(i, node) {
      var $node = $(node), mapSel = $node.attr('data-map'), $map = $(mapSel);
      $node
       .on('mouseover', function() { $map.fadeIn() })
       .on('mouseout', function() { $map.fadeOut() })
  })
})
</script>
```

Comment: This code loops through all elements that have a `data-map` attribute, and for each element it adds two handlers. The `$map` variable is a jQuery selector of the map specified in the `data-map` attribute